# Untraceable whitespace between div rows

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to "draw" a maze with JavaScript but my output drawing has some whitespace which I don't understand where it's from.

**HTML**

```
<div id="maze" style="height: 60px; width: 90px;">
    <div class="tile wall"></div>
    <div class="tile wall"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile wall"></div>
    <div class="tile wall"></div>
    ...
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
}

.tile {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: lightgrey;
}
```

Where does it come from and how do I get rid of it?

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan_Ironman/2QUB3/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using inline-block and there is whitespace in your sourcecode, there will also be whitespace in the output.

Put all `div` in one line to fix this.

---

Another solution would be to set all the elements to `display:block` and then `float:left` them, like this:

```
.tile {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: lightgrey;
    float:left;
}
```

See the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2QUB3/1/).

---

Another thing worth mentioning is, that you could safe the whole "string" to create the maze in a variable, and add all the elements at once. Take a look at my demo to see what I meant. This will make your maze much more scalable and the whole creation process way more efficient.

Comment: There is no whitespace in my HTML. Check the DOM-inspector.

Comment: Yes there is, you have a newline and some spaces before the `divs`.

Comment: Not in my DOM-inspector. Where would they come from?

Comment: Hmm, sorry i didn't read properly. It's actually an interesting question, why there is whitespace. I edited my post with another solution, which fixes your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `#maze {font-size: 0;}` to your CSS, and you're ok.
`display: inline-block;` considers line breaks as whitespaces too.

Comment: You could also comment `<!--` `-->` out the whitespace if you don't want to set `font-size: 0`, or write all elements with `inline-block` on one line. Any method of removing whitespace or line-breaks work, really.

Comment: @NilsKaspersson I really don't understand why everybody mentions whitespace, there really isn't a single whitespace char in my output code (beside the ones inside the div properties obviously).

Comment: I mentioned in my answer. Line breaks are treated as whitespaces too, and by using `innerHTML` you somehow output all your `<div>` elements with line breaks.

Comment: @TwiStar No it doesn't. The HTML above is just formatted for clarity, there are no line-breaks nor spaces in the HTML if you check the output in the fiddle.